# Prevent flashing of full text when using Jquery dotdotdot to truncate

Tags: jquery

We're using this [Jquery dotdotdot plugin](https://github.com/FrDH/jQuery.dotdotdot) to truncate some multiline HTML to a specific number of lines. It works great except that, on page load there's a flash, where the full text is initially displayed before it is truncated. We activate the plugin using the call `$(".dotdot200").dotdotdot({height:200});` on window ready. How can we prevent the flash from happening?

Comment: you can't reliably remove said flash without removing the plugin and doing it a different way. The plugin relies on the element being visible to calculate where it needs to cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try moving your `dotdotdot` call outside of window ready to get it to run earlier on.

If you can live without the `...` ellipsis, a CSS-only solution would be cleaner: https://jsfiddle.net/my87bz74/

```
p { 
  font-size:20px; 
  line-height:30px;
  height: 90px; /* line-height * amount of lines */
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using max-height instead of height because sometimes we don't need to truncate. But otherwise this works for us.

Answer (score 0):

Set your element to `overflow: hidden`, and the `height` to the same height you set in the jQuery call.

This will flash only the ellipses, and not all the extra truncated text.